# Answers deleted when the question is deleted

Tags: feature-request, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

The other day I was answering to a question by a very long text, it take me a long time to do it because I have done some research, but anyway it was on an interesting subject, so it was worth it.

Some minutes after I had post my answer, I've seen that the question has been deleted by the user and my long answer too. I was a bit angry because I feel that I had lost my time... I personnaly want to contribute to stack overflow because when I try to answer a question I often learn something by doing research on it. I think it can be also usefull to retrieve some old answers we have posted to remember how we have resolve something.

According to me, our answers and the questions should be always visible in our account page, even if the user decided to delete them. Do you think it's possible ?

Is there a concrete reason to delete answers when a question is deleted ?

Comment: Ok, so if I have understand everything we can retrieve the deleted question by the url except if the question is judged useless (question score < 0 ...) ?

Comment: You can always post OP's question as your own, with your answer.

Comment: Yes, it can be a solution. But in this case I had no idea my answer would be deleted.

Comment: do you have link of that question ? we can undelete for you if that question is constructive

Comment: I'm afraid not, it's been few days and I don't believe I can retrieve it in my browser history but thank you

Comment: can you  see your deleted  answer here http://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/993704 ?